# “background-image” style doesn't work in IE 11

Tags: html, css, linux, apache

I am trying to display the "background-image" in textarea. It works on my local machine on IIS. I moved the code to Production running on Apache. It doesn't display the image. I tried to remove single quotes with url(asterisk.png) but still doesn't work. Please let me know if there are any suggestions.

```
        <textarea id="test1" name="test1" class="required"  rows="25" cols="30" ></textarea>
```

### CSS

```
.required {
    background-image: url('asterisk.png');
    background-position:right center;               
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

[image]

Comment: is your image in the same folder as your HTML?

Comment: yes. it is in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually working. Maybe you are missing the image path.

You can see a working code here: https://embed.plnkr.co/9u6s8wvWwbQYyoj3yXQ6/

Is your image at the same path that your html code?

Answer (score 0):

try it

```css
.required {
    background-image: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/political-signs/512/red-star-communism-label-128.png);
    background-position:right center;               
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="test1" name="test1" class="required"  rows="25" cols="30" ></textarea>
```

Comment: plz give me screenshot

Comment: just uploaded screenshot.